# Настройка жизни сессий в PHP

Tags: сессия, php

Здравствуйте
Мы решили перевести сайт (интернет-магазин) с кук на сессии и нам нужно увеличить "жизнь" сессий.
Читал что можно это реализовать сменив эти параметры в php.ini.

```
session.gc_maxlifetime
session.cookie_lifetime
```

Но так же была статья о том что, файлы сессий хранясь в папке /tmp по-умолчанию очищались сборщиком мусора, который все «старые», по его меркам, сессии из папки удаляет.

Так ли это? 
И как правильно увеличить "жизнь" сессий до 7-и дней ?

Спасибо.

Comment: классно. как раз искал решение этой "проблемы".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да вы правы, такое возможно.
Указывайте директорию сессий [самостоятельно](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-save-path.php).
А так же (полагаю у вас на куках) время жизни [куки](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php), в качестве значения которой указывается `id` [сессии](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-id.php).

Таким образом, при создании сессии вешаете куку юзеру и указываете сколько ей жить, при повторном заходе если кука имеется - `id` сессии устанавливаете равным её значению.

При этом вы можете продлить жизнь куки, обновив её заново с тем же значением, но на другое время.