# Время жизни сессии на сайте

Tags: php, сессия

Здравствуйте. Меня мучает загадка, как примерно реализован ВК или Авито в плане работы с авторизацией!Везде прописано, что время жизни сессии не более 15 мин,и при закрытии браузера она умирает, ну а как же они реализовали ,что заходя под своим логином и паролем -сессия живет вечно,пока не выйдешь из аккаунта сам?

Answer (score 1):

Кроме сессий есть ещё и [Cookies](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.cookies.php) и они могут жить очень долго и хранятся на стороне клиента, т.е. в вашем браузере.

Из официальной документации:

> Cookies - это механизм хранения данных браузером удаленной машины для
> отслеживания или идентификации возвращающихся посетителей.

А чисто сессии уже давно никто не использует, старайтесь читать литературу по новее.

Comment: Про куки известно,но как же безопасность?То есть данные-логин и пароль,хранящиеся в Базе sql -если будут в куках,то можно на другом компе авторизоваться,в сессии должен быть id-шник куки

Comment: @GoodRA а никак безопасность. Если у злоумышленника будет доступ к кукам браузера, то он в любом случае сможет авторизоваться, даже если это сессия. Просто не надо подпускать злоумышленника к кукам :)

Comment: а как Авито и ВК обошли это,чтож там за технология?

Comment: @GoodRA В куках не хранит никто логины и пароли, хранят id или хэш и потом проверяют на сервере всё это, поищите примеры авторизаций с куками и всё поймете думаю

Comment: Про сессии бред прочитал

Comment: @GoodRA, Я не уверен, но для предотвращения автозавершения сессии (если пользователь набирал текст в форме, а потом на 1 час залип на видео или на чтение какой-то статьи, а потом нажал кнопку ’отправить’ и получил страницу входа, вместо отправки формы) на движение курсора вешают скрипт который "говорит" серверу, что пользователь на сайте что-то долго читает или смотрит видео.

НО хрзнает как сделать так чтобы сессия жила если юзер решил сходить в магазин за хлебушкой, или на полдня по иным делам отошел от компа. Мне тож интересно как реализовать ’вечную’ сессию.

Comment: @GoodRA вот тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/194912/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-php?rq=1

в серверных настройках это решается.